# Turtle: Call to onscreenclick not listening in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm having an issue where a call to onscreenclick is not keeping the window open and listening when I am testing using Pycharm, however it works fine when I use an online interpreter like the one found at Skultp.org or Interactivepython.org

Here is the block of code in question:

```
import turtle

def position(x, y):
    print x, y

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color("blue")
tess.shape("turtle")

wn.onscreenclick(position)
```

When I run the code above in Pycharm, the interpreter immediately runs the function 'position' and prints 'None'. Following this, the program ends.

When I run the code in the online interpreters mentioned above, the program waits for clicks and prints out the x and y coordinates of each click.

I want the call to 'onscreenclick' to behave in Pycharm as it does on the online interpreters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert `turtle.done()` as your last statement.

```
import turtle

def position(x, y):
    print x, y

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color("blue")
tess.shape("turtle")

wn.onscreenclick(position)
turtle.done()
```